# Order by a meta value "price" within a string

Tags: php, wordpress

it turns out that I want to order a meta value called "price" that is next to others like "description", etc. Each one with its value. I tried to sort it with "meta_value_num", but it does not order correctly.

Here is an excerpt from my code.

```
$sc = shortcode_atts(array('nopaging' = false, 'post_type' = 'tarifa', 'query' = '', 'registers' = '',
                            'category' = '', 'tag_name' = '', 'customprice' = 'tarifas', 'price' = '',
                            'power' = '', 'relation_operator' = '', 'meta_key' = 'tarifas',
                            'orderby' = 'meta_value_num', 'order' = 'DESC',), $atts);

$options = array('meta_key' = $sc['meta_key'], 'order_by' = $sc['orderby'], 'order' = $sc['order'],
                'category_name' = $sc['category'], 'post_type' = $sc['post_type'], 'posts_per_page' = $sc['registers'],);

if ($sc['price'] == '' and $sc['power'] == '') {
    $options['meta_query'] = array('relation' = 'AND', array('relation' = 'OR', array('key' = $sc['customprice'], 'value' = $sc['price'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',), array('key' = $sc['customprice'], 'value' = $sc['power'], 'compare' = 'LIKE',),));
    $sc['power'] = "default";
    $sc['price'] = "default";
} else {
    $options['meta_query'] = array('relation' = 'AND', array('relation' = 'OR', array('key' = $sc['customprice'], 'value' = sprintf(':"%s";',
            $sc['price']), 'compare' = 'LIKE',), array('key' = $sc['customprice'], 'value' = sprintf(':"%s";',
            $sc['power']), 'compare' = 'LIKE',),));
}

$your_loop = new WP_Query($options);
```

Answer (score 0):

My meta value is this:

a:10:{s:9:"destacado";s:9:"destacado";s:6:"precio";s:4:"4389";s:3:"sub";s:9:"IVA incl.";s:4:"logo";s:4:"Bhhh";s:8:"potencia";s:1:"4";s:8:"llamada1";s:5:"Jjjjj";s:4:"url1";s:4:"Jjjj";s:4:"desc";s:3:"Jjj";s:8:"llamada2";s:2:"Jj";s:4:"url2";s:3:"Jjj";}